# detect when price break low or high trend plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scipy

A trend line, often referred to as a line of best fit, is a line that is used to represent the behavior of a set of data to determine if there is a certain pattern. A trend line is an analytical tool used most often in conjunction with a scatter plot (a two-dimensional graph of ordered pairs) to see if there is a relationship between two variables.
this code draw high trend line and low trend line .
i trying to detect when time price break low trend or high trend .
please share your solutions. thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl as qdl
from scipy.stats import linregress
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# get AAPL 10 years data

data = qdl.get("WIKI/AAPL", start_date="2016-01-01", end_date="2016-09-01")
data0 = data.copy()
data0['date_id'] = ((data0.index.date - data0.index.date.min())).astype('timedelta64[D]')
data0['date_id'] = data0['date_id'].dt.days + 1

# high trend line

data1 = data0.copy()

while len(data1)>3:

    reg = linregress(
                    x=data1['date_id'],
                    y=data1['Adj. High'],
                    )
    data1 = data1.loc[data1['Adj. High'] > reg[0] * data1['date_id'] + reg[1]]

reg = linregress(
                    x=data1['date_id'],
                    y=data1['Adj. High'],
                    )

data0['high_trend'] = reg[0] * data0['date_id'] + reg[1]

# low trend line

data1 = data0.copy()

while len(data1)>3:

    reg = linregress(
                    x=data1['date_id'],
                    y=data1['Adj. Low'],
                    )
    data1 = data1.loc[data1['Adj. Low'] < reg[0] * data1['date_id'] + reg[1]]


reg = linregress(
                    x=data1['date_id'],
                    y=data1['Adj. Low'],
                    )

data0['low_trend'] = reg[0] * data0['date_id'] + reg[1]

# plot

data0['Adj. Close'].plot()
data0['high_trend'].plot()
data0['low_trend'].plot()
plt.show()
```

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwa0m.jpg) check this

Comment: are you asking how to compare to two columns in a dataframe (e.g., flag the values in one column that are higher than a another)?

Comment: check this please https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwa0m.jpg